# HBase - Phoenix - Rowkey

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I have table called "TEST" and I want my row_key to be like "Key:randomValue" and there is a column called "Name" and at the time of querying, how I do access "Name" column's value by using only "Key" in the query?

Comment: that feels very hbase specific, you should be able to create multiple columns to support that, eg a primary key that is key randomvalue which I believe ends up mapping some what to key:randomValue in hbase

Comment: Currently what I am doing is making a composite primary key when creating table through phoenix and those two columns are mapped to hbase as composite row keys and I am directly accessing through rowkey then, do you think this is the right way to go about it?